# Access denied for user 'myUser'@'DESKTOP-1FSAS' (using password: NO)

Tags: c#, mysql, .net

I am using C# to connect to mysql server

When using Workbench I am able to connect using the credentials I have in my connection string.

When trying to connect from C# I get the below error
`Access denied for user 'myUser'@'DESKTOP-1FSAS' (using password: NO)`

myUser has full permissions

Here is the code

```
using (MySqlConnection con = new MySqlConnection(context.Database.GetDbConnection().ConnectionString))
{

        var dateFromParam = new MySqlParameter("@DateFrom", dateFrom.Date.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd"));
        var dateToParam = new MySqlParameter("@DateTo", dateTo.Date.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd"));
        var totalRowsParam = new MySqlParameter("@Total", -1);
        totalRowsParam.Direction = System.Data.ParameterDirection.InputOutput;
        totalRowsParam.DbType = System.Data.DbType.Int32;

        MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand("CALL SPTest(@DateFrom, @DateTo, @Total)", con);
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        cmd.Parameters.Add(dateFromParam);
        cmd.Parameters.Add(dateToParam);
        cmd.Parameters.Add(totalRowsParam);

        await con.OpenAsync();
}
```

Why am I getting this exception?

Comment: Can you access the database with eg. Workbench using your Windows Credentials?

Comment: Yes. I think I found the issue. I was using ef core context to get connection string and for some reason EF changes the connection string. In my appsettings I have the correct string which I just used and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

Check if the user has permissions to access the database (or tables), it may be trivial but it has happened to me in the past:

```
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'myUser'@'localhost';
```

Let me know if it helped!